# How can I see the pixel height to width ratio in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to see the width to height ratio of pixels in Photoshop?  I think I saw it some other day, but I can't find it now.

Something like "2:1 pixel ratio" means that the picture is exactly twice as wide as high. Of course, I could use math to find this thing myself – from the maximum amount of pixel width and height, but I need quick way to find it on loads of pictures.

Using Photoshop CS5.

Comment: The word your looking for is pixel "Aspect Ratio", look in the VIEW menu. I dont have 5 but they added some aspect stuff since my version. Also seeing it in Image - Image size, is possible if you whip out some math in your head. Also Image - Pixels aspect http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pm3TezWpyoA

Comment: Sadly the answer is no, as far as I'm aware. Paint Shop Pro used to show you the aspect ratio, IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

In CS5 I'm not sure about it. This is how it works in CS6, possibly in CS5 as well.

Select crop tool. The tool preferences/presets panel will show you a different set of stuff as shown in the picture below.

[image]

If you click on the drop down where it says 'Original Ratio', you will see the following options.

[image]

---

This way you can crop to what ratio you wish, however I do not think there's a way of seeing your current ratio.